# Having a large area from which other areas are subtracted, how to split the large area in parts that already don't cover the subtracted areas?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, area

Having a large area described by lines that don't cross each other and where the last point equals the first point, and having other areas of the same sort that subtract from the large area, is there a formula to split the  large area in parts, so when drawing only the parts there is no need anymore to subtract anything?

Like I have a lake that I want to draw, but the island in it and the pier that reaches from the shore over the water should not drawn blue.

I assume there is already a method developed for this. What is it called, so I could look it up? Or even better is the method explainable in a view words?

Comment: A convex hull approach doesn't work. And it's frequently possible to break up plane figures into triangles: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull

Comment: Thinking a bit about the question there is an easy solution it seems to me, though I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say convex hull might work, but I couldn't edit. There's an algorithm for generating the convex hull, but I don't recall its name. I think there's a theorem than any convex polygon with N vertices can be broken into n-2 triangles.

Answer (score 0):

Given that in general the regions are complicated, I would simply use any of the innumerable software packages to discretize the region.

In *Mathematica*:

```
DiscretizeRegion[
 RegionDifference[
 RegionDifference[
   Disk[{0, 0}, 2], Disk[{0, 0}, .4]],
   Rectangle[{.8, -.2}, {2, .2}]]
 ]
```

[image: discretized pond, island and dock]

---

By the way, I have no idea what this single ungrammatical sentence means:

"Having a large area described by lines that don't cross each other and where the last point equals the first point, and having other areas of the same sort that subtract from the large area, is there a formula to split the large area in parts, so when drawing only the parts there is no need anymore to subtract anything?"